# Why do I read my own transferred data during my RS485 serial comms?

Tags: serial, esp32, softwareserial, rs485

I am writing a RS485 serial communication firmware for the ESP32 (the minimal code is at the end of the question you can paste it as an Arduino INO or in platformIO main.cpp file).

It is quite simple: it asks for commands on a regular basis, say command ID 0x92, in the form of `0xA5 0x40 0x92 0x08 etc.`on 13 bytes and the master is expected to send the response back in the form `0xA5 0x01 0x92 0x08 etc.`as a 13-byte packet as well. So far so good.

As you certainly noticed `A5` is a constant header, `0x40` is used to ask the master (whilst `0x01` marks an incoming message) and `0x92` is the message ID we are interested in.

The logs are as follows, and as you can see, my reading portion of code received my own sent message followed by the response.

I am trying to understand why: a design flow in my code? flush() does not actually flush? or whatever I should do to fix it?

```
18:38:14.936 -> Starting RS485 serial comm @ 9600 SWSERIAL_8N1
18:38:14.936 -> #1: Asking for command 00
18:38:14.936 -> Writing command: 
18:38:14.936 -> =====> a5 40 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ed …
18:38:16.946 -> Asking for command 90
18:38:16.946 -> Writing command: 
18:38:16.946 -> =====> a5 40 90 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7d …
18:38:18.963 -> Asking for command 91
18:38:18.963 -> Writing command: 
18:38:18.963 -> =====> a5 40 91 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7e …
18:38:20.986 -> Asking for command 92
18:38:20.986 -> Writing command: 
18:38:20.986 -> =====> a5 40 92 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f …
18:38:22.977 -> Received some bytes as follows:
18:38:23.011 -> <===== a5 40 92 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f a5 01 92 08 00 01 ff 01 fa 01 03 d6 15 
18:38:23.011 -> Let ask once more!
```

And the code I wrote is as follows:

```cpp
/// RS 485 test lab for ESP32
/// Minimal firmware for testing the SBM IoT RS485
/// Created by Sdl on Friday January 7th 2021 10:43am @ Will's N Hoagland Blvd in Kissimme, FL, USA

#include "SoftwareSerial.h"


#define RXD GPIO_NUM_19
#define TXD GPIO_NUM_18 

#define PACKET_HEADER_LENGTH 4
#define PACKET_LENGTH 13

// == Software serial bound to TX RX 18/19
SoftwareSerial s(RXD, TXD, false);

/**
 * Computes the check sum
 * @param {[uint8]} data The data buffer 
 * @param {Number} length The number of bytes 
 * @returns The ine-byte checksum
 */
uint8_t checksum(uint8_t *buffer) {
  const int length = PACKET_LENGTH - 1;

  uint8_t checksum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    checksum += buffer[i];
  }
  return checksum&0xff;
}

// == Build the remote master
#define MASTER 0x40



int messageCount = 0;

/// Sneds a message whose ID is the given [id]
void sendMessage(uint8_t id) {
  Serial.printf("Asking for command %02x", id); Serial.println();

  uint8_t command[PACKET_LENGTH] = {
    //Head  Master, Id: Soc   Length    Data 1, 2,    3     4     5     6     7     8     cs
    0xA5, MASTER, id,     8,        0x00,   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
  };

  send(command);
}

void send(uint8_t *buffer) {
  const int length = PACKET_LENGTH;
  
  // == Compute command checksum
  buffer[PACKET_LENGTH-1] = checksum(buffer);
  
  //digitalWrite(TXD, HIGH); //enable sending
  
  // == Write command
  Serial.println("Writing command: ");
  Serial.print("=====> ");

  for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    Serial.printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
  }
  Serial.println("…");
  
  //size_t count = 
  s.write(buffer, length);

  // == Disable transmitter 
  s.flush();
  s.drain();

  //digitalWrite(TXD, LOW); //back to receiving
  //log("sent %d bytes", count);

  delay(2000);
}

uint8_t commands[] = {
  0x00,
  0x90,
  0x91,
  0x92,
  0x93,
  0x94,
  0x95,
  0x96,
  0x97,
  0x98,
  0xD8,
};
int commandsCounter = 0;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);



  // == Start comms
  Serial.println("Starting RS485 serial comm @ 9600 SWSERIAL_8N1");
  s.begin(9600, SWSERIAL_8N1, RXD, TXD, false, 256);




  Serial.printf("#%d: ", ++messageCount);

  for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    sendMessage(commands[i]);
    commandsCounter++;
  }
}

void loop() {

    // == Now wait for reading

    if (s.available()) {
      Serial.println("Received some bytes as follows:");
      Serial.print("<===== ");
     

      int i=0;
      int messageId = 0;
      while(s.available()) {
        uint8_t b = s.read();
        Serial.printf("%02x ",b);
      }

      Serial.println();

  
      
      // == Ask again
      Serial.println("Let ask once more!");
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("No bytes to read: ask for the SoC");
    }      

    

    // == Wait for 5 secs
    delay(5000);

    // == Ask BMS for message
    Serial.printf("#%d: ", ++messageCount);
    sendMessage(commands[commandsCounter++]);

    // == Loops thru the commands vector
    if (commandsCounter>=sizeof(commands)) commandsCounter = 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Not sure this is the case here, but I have seen a number of RS232 level shifters that cause this behavior. Try disconnecting everything from the TX/RX pins and test that you don't get echo in that case.

Comment: @PMF Oh really? That counts for one direction to search! Thanks!

Comment: How did you wire the “transmit enable” and the “receiver enable” pins of your transceiver?

Comment: If you keep your receiver enabled while sending, of course you will receive your sent message. The RS485 serial communication is a bus, there are no separated lines for the different directions.

Comment: Is it 2- or 4-wire RS485 (half/full-duplex)? Which transceiver do you use?